# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.preferencefragment.R$layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a class that extends `android.support.v4.PreferenceFragment`. When I run the app I first get this warning on LogCat:

```
04-02 14:22:57.113: W/dalvikvm(28828): VFY: unable to resolve static field 656 (preference_list_fragment) in Landroid/support/v4/preferencefragment/R$layout;
```

Then upon tapping an option on the app's UI, it shuts down and this error appears on LogCat

```
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.preferencefragment.R$layout
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment.onCreateView(PreferenceFragment.java:95)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-02 14:22:57.158: E/AndroidRuntime(28828):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have gone through many posts about the same problem, and I did all of the following already:

- Downloaded `PreferenceFragment` from https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment, imported it as a project, and added it as a required project to my buildpath.
- Tried that last step with the code from https://github.com/escrichov/guide/tree/master/android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master as well
- Added `android-support-v4.jar` in the `libs` folder, and added it to my build path
- Added `android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master.jar` in the `libs` folder, and added it to my build path
- Checked the android-support-v4-prerferencefragment in the Order and Export tab of Java Build Path
- Tried right clicking my project-> Android tools -> Add support library
- Cleaned the project after each of those changes
- Downloaded `Android Support Library` and `Android Support Repository` from the Android SDK Manager.

But still the problem persists.

I am testing on a nexus 10

Comment: Looks to me like it's unable to find `res/layout/preference_list_fragment.xml` in your apk for some reason.  It appears to be available in https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment so perhaps you're not including that project in your own properly?

Comment: Please explain what "added it as a required project to my buildpath" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean that I added it from the Projects tab in the Java build path

Comment: @mharper That file is in the android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master project that I imported. Is there something that should be done further than adding that project to the Java build path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, never mess with the build path manually.

The project you are trying to use is an Android library project. There are [instructions for adding a dependency on an Android library project to your Eclipse project](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). Given that you have imported it into your Eclipse workspace, you need to add it as a dependency via the Android portion of your project settings:

[image: Android Project Properties]

Click the Add button, choose this library project from the dialog, click OK to close up each dialog, and you should be set.

Comment: After doing this I came across an error that says `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define` the solution was to simply remove all traces of `android-support-v4-preferencefragment-master` from the libs folder and Java Build Path. Those were leftovers from previous attempts to solve the problem.